# Connection timeout when trying to SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp

The other day I tried to connect to my remote server via SSH as i always have.  But now when I try to connect it just times out after about 60 seconds.  I run

```
service ssh start
```

Which tells me that Job is already running: ssh.  I then ran

```
$netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2030/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2157/perl           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3028/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2273/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2618/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      2291/proftpd: (acce 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3028/sshd
```

I am able to access subdomains on my site, and FTP, but don't have the ability to SSH or even ping remotely.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check your local firewall rules?

Comment: Did you check your log for messages related to sshd? `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/secure` or something similar...

Comment: I ran `cat /var/log/aut.log | grep sshd` and got the [following](http://pastebin.com/E2V7RZxK)

Comment: It doesn't mention any connection attempt from a remote machine. This could be a firewall or iptables issue.

Comment: its a relatively fresh install of ubuntu, I don't have iptables installed (yet).  Is there something else that could be blocking it?  Or should i install iptables to allow access to sshd?

Comment: I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

- To exclude a problem at your end (not on the server), run ssh with the `-v` argument to see what is going on.
- `telnet <server-ip> 22` will tell you if your connection reaches the server. It should respond with something like `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH...`.
- Check the server's log files (e.g. `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/secure`) for any sshd-related messages. You should see connection attempts from your remote IP address if the connection reaches the server.
- If your connection cannot reach your server's ssh port, this could have different reasons:

  - Routing problem (in this case, connections to other ports should no go through, too.)
  - External firewall blocking the connection.
  - Local firewall (iptables) blocking the connection. Check with `iptables -L` if you have any rules installed.
  - If you have `denyhosts` or `fail2ban` installed, then your IP is maybe blacklisted. Check your `/etc/hosts.deny` and the related log file.

Comment: Thanks for all of the ideas this is what i came up with.  ssh -v tells me the Operation timed out.  Telnet has done the same thing also saying 'Unable to connect to remote host'.  /var/log/auth.log does not give me any information about remote connections (i have no /var/log/secure).  iptables, denyhosts, fail2ban aren't installed.  /etc/hosts.deny is all commented out.  Maybe its time to learn wireshark?

Comment: Just to make sure: You checked the log file on the server, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, the only thing i saw wast the pam_unix cron job in auth.log.  There is no /var/log/secure on my filesystem.

Comment: If you suspect that your IP address might be temporarily blacklisted (by whatever mechanism), you could try to connect from a different IP address.